# Flex Remote object call disconnect issue

Tags: java, apache-flex, remoting

Working on flex application using java remote object calls. There is a cancel operation(a button on progress bar) which needs to kill/disconnect the operation/process on server. 
Here is how I am doing - 
ServiceLocator.getInstance().getRemoteObject(Services.REMOTE_OBJECT).disconnect();

But its not killing the session/ java process - not sure why. Any tip is helpful

Comment: It won't kill java , I guess that it will just ignore the response from java to be listened by the Responder in your cairngorm-flex app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disconnect will simply destroy the connection. You wont be able to kill Java process or destroy the java session. To destroy your session you will need to issue a logout on your channel.